# Provider pactVerify isn't picking up JSON Pact file

Tags: gradle, groovy, kotlin, pact

I have two projects in the same repo, with completely separate directory structures (consumer in `/test-consumer`, provider in `/app`).

The consumer check outputs a JSON Pact file in `/test-consumer/build/pacts`, as expected by

```
dependencies { test { systemProperties['pact.rootDir'] = "$buildDir/pacts" } }
```

I then copy the file into `/app/build/pacts/`, and put this same `systemProperties` line into my provider's `build.gradle`.

The sample project that I'm plagiarising from is using a Pact broker, so I guessed I can take that out, and replace it with the `rootDir`, but it's not working. This is what I get:

> `WARNING: There are no consumers to verify for provider 'Coffee Ordering Provider'`

So, it seems like it's finding the Pact files, but can't find a provider+consumer pair in any of them.

**TL;DR:
What am I doing wrong?**

Here are some code bits to help:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  test { systemProperties['pact.rootDir'] = "$buildDir/pacts" }
}

pact {
  serviceProviders {
    'Coffee Ordering Provider' {
      port = 8080

      startProviderTask = startProvider
      terminateProviderTask = stopProvider
      stateChangeUrl = url('http://localhost:8080/pactStateChange')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that warning because you have not told the pact plugin where to find the pact files. For pacts in a directory, add the following:

```
pact {
  serviceProviders {
    'Coffee Ordering Provider' {
      port = 8080

      startProviderTask = startProvider
      terminateProviderTask = stopProvider
      stateChangeUrl = url('http://localhost:8080/pactStateChange')

      hasPactsWith('Coffee Ordering Consumers') {

          // Will define a consumer for each pact file in the directory.
          // Consumer name is read from contents of pact file
          pactFileLocation = file("$buildDir/pacts")

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just a note that you were setting the `pact.rootDir` for all tests, but the pact verification does not run as a test.

Comment: What is the relevance of the `String` parameter to `hasPactsWith`?

Comment: Maybe there could be a more specific error if no Pact files are found, too? :3

Comment: The `String` parameter to `hasPactsWith` has no effect. It was initially put in to provide some type of grouping of consumers.